# Is there a macro that can be used in a C++ project in Visual Studio to identify the current SOLUTION configuration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, macros

I have a VS2008 solution in which there is a C++ project (we'll name it Project1 for clarity's sake). The project's purpose is to test the executable generated by the compilation of another C++ project (Project2) in the same solution. The executable being tested (Project2.exe) is built in the same folder than the executable generated by our Project1 (Project1.exe). Here's what is looks like in the build folder:

Build_path/Debug

- Project1_Debug.exe
- Project2_Debug.exe

Build_path/Release

- Project1.exe
- Project2.exe

**The project Project1 is set in the Configuration Manager to always build in debug (even when the solution build in release)**, since there is a problem with one of the third party tool used in Project1 when we compile in release. So any preprocessor definitions that would identify Project1's configuration would always be set to debug. Knowing this and the fact that Project2 build in release when the Solution Configuration is set to build in release, **how can project1 locate project2 when building the solution in release, since it always search in the same folder it is located in**?

Constraint(s):

- I cannot change the build folder structure
- As mentioned, using Project1's preprocessor definitions with a macro such as `$(Configuration)` won't help here, since `$(Configuration)` would be bound to Project1's configuration and **would always be set to debug**.

I am using `GetModuleFileName` to fetch Project1's executable and from that location (which is always in the debug folder), the only solution I found was to search for a macro representing the current solution configuration, which would help me to fetch Project2.exe in the release folder when building my solution in release (but Project1 still in debug) by adding `../Release` in my path and stay in the debug folder when Project2 is actually in the debug folder (when the solution is built in debug) by adding `../Debug` in my path.

A little pseudo-code would look like this:

```
If SOLUTION_CONFIGURATION == DEBUG // Project 1 and Project2 is in debug folder 
  add ../Debug in my research path to locate Project2_Debug.exe from Project1_Debug.exe's location
Else if SOLUTION_CONFIGURATION == RELEASE // Project1 is in debug and Project2 is in release folder
  add ../Release in my research path to locate Project2.exe from Project1_Debug.exe's location
End if
```

Comment: Can you just use `GetModuleFileName()` to find out where your executable is located, and adjust the path accordingly? Alternatively, you can probably use the `C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions` field in the Project Properties dialog to define your own pre-processor macro that uses one of the VC++ build macros (i.e. `$(Configuration)` would give you "Debug" or "Release")

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thanks for the quick response. I will add some details to the question to answer your propositions. But, the thing is, I exactly want to do what you're telling me and adjust from `GetModuleFileName` which I already use to fetch the executable path, **but can't do it if there's no solution configuration macro**, since I would be forced to hardcode either `../Release` or `../Debug` in front of the path and there would be a configuration I wouldn't be able to test.

Comment: Well, I haven't searched for "visual studio predefined macros" in a while.  There is a list of what is available.  Perhaps one meets your needs.  Here's [the macro list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no *standardard* macros for representing configurations and version information.

However, MS maintains a list of [predefined macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx) for Visual Studio.

Some may be available with other compilers.

P.S. I found the site by searching the internet using the keywords "Visual Studio predefined macros".

Comment: Indeed. This goes unspecified by the ISO C++ Standardard.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for the response! Man I'm dumb. I was aware of the existence of the predefined macros on the MSDN, but in the rush, I didn't realize that the answer was right in front of me and just didn't think to look at it. To my temporary problem, I'll have a temporary solution which will involve changing the project properties in release to compile in debug and put the binaries in the release folder. I love SO, first question ever and 20 minutes later I have my answer.